# Custom View don't show by adding UIView in storyboard to inherit from the customed class

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, custom-view

I wrote a custom view class named MyCustomView.swift with the MyCustomView.xib.
When I use

```
let customView = MyCustomView(frame:.....)
self.view.addSubView(customView)
```

The custom view will appear.

But when I add a UIView in Storyboard directly, and choose the MyCustomView as the class of Custom Class, it don't show. Even I set the background color of the UIView, it don't work. Especially when I Annotate the MyCustomview with @IBDesignable, two error warning showes,

```
Failed to render and update auto layout status fo XXXViewController
Failed to update auto layout status
```

Does that mean I should set auto layout for the custom view in storyboard?

This is MyCustomView.class

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable
class MyCustomView:UIView{
@IBOutlet weak var categoryLabel: UILabel!

var category:String = ""{
    didSet{
        self.categoryLabel.text = category
    }
}
var intro:String = ""
var address:String = ""
var distance:CGFloat = 0.0


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    awakeFromNib()
    print("\(#function)")
}
convenience init(){
    print("\(#function)")
    self.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    print("\(#function)")
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    awakeFromNib()

}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyCustomView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UIView
    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth.union(.flexibleHeight)
    addSubview(view)
}
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}

}
```

Comment: please add code for your `MyCustomView` class. how you add the xib file?

Comment: @hafiz This my MyCustomView.class code

Comment: @Leo I tried .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is prefix `@IBInspectable` before your `var`s.

Here is an example: custom class: **Rainbow.swift**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class Rainbow: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var firstColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: (37.0/255.0), green: (252.0/255), blue: (244.0/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
    @IBInspectable var secondColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: (171.0/255.0), green: (250.0/255), blue: (81.0/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
    @IBInspectable var thirdColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: (238.0/255.0), green: (32.0/255), blue: (53.0/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
    
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    func addOval(_ lineWidth: CGFloat, path: CGPath, strokeStart: CGFloat, strokeEnd: CGFloat, strokeColor: UIColor, fillColor: UIColor, shadowRadius: CGFloat, shadowOpacity: Float, shadowOffsset: CGSize) {
        
        let arc = CAShapeLayer()
        arc.lineWidth = lineWidth
        arc.path = path
        arc.strokeStart = strokeStart
        arc.strokeEnd = strokeEnd
        arc.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor
        arc.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
        arc.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        arc.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
        arc.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        arc.shadowOffset = shadowOffsset
        layer.addSublayer(arc)
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Add ARCs
        self.addCirle(80, capRadius: 20, color: self.firstColor)
        self.addCirle(150, capRadius: 20, color: self.secondColor)
        self.addCirle(215, capRadius: 20, color: self.thirdColor)
    }
    
    func addCirle(_ arcRadius: CGFloat, capRadius: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
        let X = self.bounds.midX
        let Y = self.bounds.midY
        
        // Bottom Oval
        let pathBottom = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: (X - (arcRadius/2)), y: (Y - (arcRadius/2)), width: arcRadius, height: arcRadius)).cgPath
        self.addOval(20.0, path: pathBottom, strokeStart: 0, strokeEnd: 0.5, strokeColor: color, fillColor: UIColor.clear, shadowRadius: 0, shadowOpacity: 0, shadowOffsset: CGSize.zero)
        
        // Middle Cap
        let pathMiddle = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: (X - (capRadius/2)) - (arcRadius/2), y: (Y - (capRadius/2)), width: capRadius, height: capRadius)).cgPath
        self.addOval(0.0, path: pathMiddle, strokeStart: 0, strokeEnd: 1.0, strokeColor: color, fillColor: color, shadowRadius: 5.0, shadowOpacity: 0.5, shadowOffsset: CGSize.zero)
        
        // Top Oval
        let pathTop = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: (X - (arcRadius/2)), y: (Y - (arcRadius/2)), width: arcRadius, height: arcRadius)).cgPath
        self.addOval(20.0, path: pathTop, strokeStart: 0.5, strokeEnd: 1.0, strokeColor: color, fillColor: UIColor.clear, shadowRadius: 0, shadowOpacity: 0, shadowOffsset: CGSize.zero)
        
    }
}
```

It draws [image: Rainbow]

Source: https://www.appcoda.com/ibdesignable-ibinspectable-tutorial/

> Try add this code :

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        xibSetup()
    }

    func xibSetup() {
        guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = 
                    [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
        contentView = view
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
        guard let nibName = nibName else { return nil }
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        return nib.instantiate(
                    withOwner: self, 
                    options: nil).first as? UIView
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! But the error disappeared, But the UIView Still not show.Only by code in ViewController can I draw the view.

Comment: When you draw a view through code, you will see the effects only when you run your project.

Comment: Click your custom view object and in the Identity inspector set the **_Module_ ** to `IBDesignable`
like shown here http://imgur.com/a/t3LJR

Comment: But does IBDesignable is just a module or group in that project?

Comment: I tried the rainbow, it works well. But my view is awaken from xib, it can not work

Comment: added some code, please check, if my answer helped you, please accept it by clicking the check mark.

Comment: You may also find this useful : https://medium.com/zenchef-tech-and-product/how-to-visualize-reusable-xibs-in-storyboards-using-ibdesignable-c0488c7f525d

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the `@IBDesignable` because Xcode is looking for `IBInspectable` properties in your class which is not exist

Comment: You're right. But that's not my key point. Without \@IBDesignable, the uiview in storyboard still can not show. I think the \@IBDesignable just in another aspect showes my mistaking in use custom view. But the by code in Viewcontroller the view works well.

Comment: @周雪静 but that remove the `Failed to render and update auto layout` right. Add `IBInspectable` property probably will render it to your storyboard

Comment: no the error disappear but the view don't . I try alternatively use code to draw in view. It works. But xib didn't